# jQuery selectors for Laravel pagination in standart and modal content

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I have a pagination on page and in modal window (modal content is loaded with ajax). How can I write selectors right? Href in modal fires twice, non-modal zero.

```js
$('body').on('click', ':not(.modal-content) .pagination a', function(e) {
    console.log('standart pagination'); // fires none
});

$('body').on('click', '.modal-content .pagination a', function(e) {
    console.log('modal pagination'); // fires from both
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination">
   <a href="#">page 1</a>
</div>
<div class="modal-example">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div>
          <div class="pagination">
             <a href="#">page 1 modal</a>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Try it on:
https://www.bootply.com/q7B3mr1OWQ

Thanks you for help

---

In the end, I use this solution:

```
$('body').on('click', '.pagination a', function(e) {
  if($(this).parents('.modal-content').length !== 0) {
    return;
  }

    console.log('standart pagination'); // fires from both
});

$('body').on('click', '.modal-content .pagination a', function(e) {
    console.log('modal pagination'); // fires from both
});
```

Comment: Fix your HTML first.

Comment: Fixed, but HTML here is only example.

Comment: why don't you try assigning `id` and attaching `event` using that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working because you are saying find any element which is not a `.modal-content` then find pagination links within it. there are two possible problems with this as you have found:

1. If the pagination element is directly in the body, there is no parent element to check against for having `.modal-content`. That is why the standard link doesn't do anything.
2. For a link inside a `.modal-content`, if there is any other parent element , it will fire the standard handler. This is why you get both messages for the second link.

I don't think you can get the correct set of links to apply the event handler to just by using a selector, unless you add a class to the pagination links themselves to identify them being modal or not.

There are a couple of ways around this. You can get hold of all pagination links, then filter them to get those with a `.modal-content` parent, and those without, and attach the relevant event handler to them:

```js
var paginationLinks = $('.pagination a');

paginationLinks.filter(function() {
  return $(this).parents('.modal-content').length === 0;
}).on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('standard pagination');
});

paginationLinks.filter(function() {
  return $(this).parents('.modal-content').length > 0;
}).on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('modal pagination');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination">
   <a href="#">page 1</a>
</div>
<div class="modal-example">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div>
          <div class="pagination">
             <a href="#">page 1 modal</a>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Another option would be to check if the element is within a modal-content within the event handler:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.pagination a', function(e) {
    if($(this).parents('.modal-content').length === 0) {
      console.log('standard pagination');
    } else {
      console.log('modal pagination');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination">
   <a href="#">page 1</a>
</div>
<div class="modal-example">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div>
          <div class="pagination">
             <a href="#">page 1 modal</a>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I accept your solution, but use only one condition from it. My final solution is in question.